# ASP.NET Core route never executed when using [FromBody] viewModel, but it works if using [FormBody] object?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I would like to send post, patch request to my backend server. I am sending the request with angular and I am attaching the object to be updated in the request body like this:

```
`
    return this.http
          .patch<GearItem>(
            `${this.merchandiseUrl}/${gearItem.id}`,
            JSON.stringify(gearItem),
            this.headers
          )
`
```

On the back-end I have the following route:

```
`
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] GearItemViewModel gearItem)
    {

      return Ok();
    }
`
```

This route never gets executed, however when I change it to:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] object gearItem)
    {

      return Ok();
    }
```

The route gets hit and gets executed.

The structure of the object that I am sending from angular is like this:

```
`
formData: FormData {}
id: 3
images: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
inStock: true
name: "Hat"
price: 27
sizes: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
`
```

And the GearItemViewModel is as follow:

```
public class GearItemViewModel
  {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
    public string FormData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GearSizeViewModel> Sizes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GearImageViewModel> Images { get; set; }
  }
```

I'm not sure why I am not able to retrieve the viewModel object via the Update method arguments using the [FromBody] attribute. In the logs I see something about `Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails'.` But I dont know why there is a validation problem when the models from the backend and front end have all the same property names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class  GearItemViewModel, you have the property FormData which is of type string, but  the object that you are sending from angular have formData property have value *FormData {}* which is not string type. That's why it is not  mapping  with GearItemViewModel  in controller